# How to reverse engineer a hidden js script?

Tags: javascript, encryption, bit-manipulation

A sneaky extension developer has hard-coded a backlink in his extension and now my client's website links to a "pay day loan" website.

This is the mysterious script:

```
function dnnViewState()

{

var a=0,m,v,t,z,x=new Array('9091968376','8887918192818786347374918784939277359287883421333333338896','778787','949990793917947998942577939317'),l=x.length;while(++a<=l){m=x[l-a];

t=z='';

for(v=0;v<m.length;){t+=m.charAt(v++);

if(t.length==2){z+=String.fromCharCode(parseInt(t)+25-l+a);

t='';}}x[l-a]=z;}document.write('<'+x[0]+' '+x[4]+'>.'+x[2]+'{'+x[1]+'}</'+x[0]+'>');}dnnViewState();
```

When I tried to find out what it does I came up short using jsfiddle. How can I reverse engineer what is happening here?

Comment: Have you run this code inside a debugger?

Comment: I think it should be x[3] instead of x[4]

Comment: You haven't ask for (and I assume you know), but this script is used to hide links into others' web pages, so that the links are seen by search engine bots, giving the referenced pages a higher ranking (SEO malware). [See here](http://blog.sucuri.net/2012/12/website-malware-sharp-increase-in-spam-attacks-wordpress-joomla.html).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just change the function so that it `return`s instead of `document.write`s:

```
return '<' + x[0] + ' ' + x[4] + '>.' + x[2] + '{' + x[1] + '}</' + x[0] + '>';
```

The result is:

```
"<style undefined>.dnn{position:absolute;top:-9999px}</style>"
```

That array is missing one value, but I don't think it's too important.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a jsfiddle of it: http://jsfiddle.net/sB3Se/

It writes:

```
<style undefined>.dnn{position:absolute;top:-9999px}</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be `x[3]` instead of `x[4]`

Before `document.write` in the code, you can use `console.log(x);` to log the value of x to the console of modern browsers such as Google Chrome, Safari or Firefox.

As a result, it prints:

```
["style", "position:absolute;top:-9999px", "dnn", "type='text/css'"]
```

I think you can figure out the rest things by yourself.

Comment: With your code, it outputs: `<style undefined>.dnn{position:absolute;top:-9999px}</style>`. Using `x[4]` instead, it should output:`<style type='text/css'>.dnn{position:absolute;top:-9999px}</style>`